# I am getting a error [ error: expected unqualified-id before ‘&’ token ] in a c++ program

Tags: c++, operator-keyword, subscript

I am getting a unusual error:

> error: expected unqualified-id before ‘&’ token

***Source code:***

```
// Overloading the c++ array subscript operator [ ]

#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

const int size=10;

class myArray
{
      int a[size];
    public:
      myArray()
      {}
      int & operator [](int);
      void print_array();   
};

int myArray & operator [](int x) // This is the line where error is as by compiler
{
          return a[x];
}

void myArray::print_array()
{
    for (int j=0; j < 10; j++)
        cout<<"array["<<j<<"] = "<<a[j]<<"\n";
}

int main()
{
    myArray instance;
    for (int i=0; i < size; i++)
     {
       instance[i] = i;
     }  
    instance.print_array();

    cout<<"\n\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You defined your `print_array` method correctly, which means that you are familiar with C++ syntax for method definitions. Yet, the syntax in the `operator []` definition is completely screwed up to the point of becoming a meaningless sequence of tokens. How is that possible?

Comment: I am learning the concept of operator overloading and I have also tried the way as recommended below, but with no success

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell the compiler that your operator [] function is a member of myArray:

```
int & myArray::operator [](const int x) 
{
          return a[x];
}
```

For more info, [this page](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/98-overloading-the-subscript-operator/) has decent examples.

Comment: After doing the above I am getting a lot of error: [link] (cl.ly/5hUN)

Comment: Compile C++ code with `g++`, not `gcc`. And turn on warnings! Add `-Wall` in the `g++` parameters.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your definition of the `operator []`

```
int myArray & operator [](int x) // This is the line where error is as by compiler
{
          return a[x];
}
```

Should be:

```
int & myArray::operator [](const int x) 
{
          return a[x];
}
```

Also, as an suggestion [] is usually overloaded so as to avoid crossing the array bounds. So your [] overloading should ideally check `x` against `size` before dereferencing the array at that index. Without such an checking the whole purpose of overloading the [] is defeated.

Comment: "Without such an checking the whole purpose of overloading the [] is defeated." -- No it isn't. The purpose of overloading it is to provide an array-like interface, not to check bounds. Though that certainly is a correct thing to do.

Comment: @Xeo: An array like interface without bounds checking, whats the use of that?

Comment: @Samrat Mazumdar: You are using `gcc` to compile a C++ source code. Use `g++` and it will compile properly. You can use `g++` to compile both C as well as C++ source code and most of the times it will be fine but not vice versa. Heres a codepad link with the above modification, http://codepad.org/sOLpXE35, it works.